# Enable / disable Quill on demand

Tags: javascript, quill

I'm using quill to make myDiv editable like this:

```
var myQuill = new Quill(myDiv, {
                modules: {
                    toolbar: {
                        container: myToolbar
                    }
                },
                styles: false,
                theme: 'snow'
            });
```

I also want Quill to become active or not active (the user cannot edit contents anymore) on demand (e.g. by pressing a button).

Is there something like `myQuill.disable()` or `myQuill.enable()`?

Comment: To the person who voted for closing: please note that, the quill website recommends to post quill related question here. Also there is a `quill` tag just for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't see a Quill command for that, but you could use this to disable it :

```
$("#DIV_ID .ql-editor").attr('contenteditable', false);
```

where `DIV_ID` is your element id chosen when initializing Quill.

For all editors, use the following :

```
$(".ql-editor").attr('contenteditable', false);
```

Change `false` to `true` to enable back.

Comment: Euh, I forgot to ask. Do you use jQuery ?

Comment: got it with `myQuill.root.contentEditable = true | false`

Answer (score 1):

Both `enable()` and `disable()` exist in Quill [1.0](http://beta.quilljs.com/docs/api/#enable) for this purpose. In Quill 0.20 they are under the `editor` instance variable so you can do `myQuill.editor.enable()`.

Comment: `console.log(myQuill.enable)` --> `undefined`. It seems not to be there in v0.20.1

Comment: My mistake, with v0.20.1 it was organized under the editor instance variable so `myQuill.editor.enable()` should work. In 1.0 myQuill.enable() works. I'll update my answer to reflect this.